# How to stream MPEG video using RTP using VLC command line

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, vlc-media-player, video-streaming, mpeg

I'm attempting to convert the following vlc command line which is streaming an MPEG video over UDP ( no RTP ):

```
cvlc -vvv /vlc/attract.mpg :norm=ntsc :v4l2-width=320 :v4l2-height=240 :v4l2-standard=45056 :channel=1 --no-sout-audio --sout '#transcode{vb="1600",vcodec=mpgv,acodec=mpga,venc=ffmpeg}:standard{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=10.0.11.255:9001}' --loop --ttl 1
```

Now I would like to do the same thing but stream as RTP multicast. For the life of me I can't seem to figure out the needed vlc command line to do so.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i don't know all the parameters of the command but i can point you to where you should put your effort in it's under #transcode > :standard > access there you need to change from udp to rtp - there may also be other parameters you also need to change so the stream is compatible with rtp. - if you have a linux and vlc on there you can use the gui client to click things together and then grab out the constructed command line command from it. and it's always a good start to use the wiki https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Advanced_Streaming_Using_the_Command_Line/#access_2

Comment: @konqui Thanks for the comment. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

It is not particularly difficult. I could do it by slightly modifying your command line this way:

> ```
> cvlc -vvv video.mpeg :norm=ntsc :v4l2-width=320 :v4l2-height=240 :v4l2-standard=45056 :channel=1 --no-sout-audio --sout '#transcode{vb="1600",vcodec=mpgv,acodec=mpga,venc=ffmpeg}:rtp{proto=udp,mux=ts,dst=239.255.0.1,port=9001}' --loop --ttl 1
> ```

I can see the video running on another shell:

> ```
> vlc rtp://@239.255.0.1:9001
> ```

I am using VLC version 2.2.0-pre3 Weatherwax (revision 2.2.0-pre3-0-ga15bef7), taken from Debian package.